# Does electric field polarity matter for Taylor cone formation?

Tags: electric-fields, metals

For example in [liquid metal ion source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_metal_ion_source) (LMIS), the positive electrode is wetted by gallium, which forms a [Taylor cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_cone) towards the negative electrode and emits Ga+ ions. Would a Taylor cone still form if field polarity was reversed?

[image]([source](http://www.chromacademy.com/images/Electrospray-p-3.jpg))
[image]([source](http://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlehtml/2012/an/c2an35249d))

Answer (score 1):

With reverse polarity, Taylor cone would still form but the polarity would cause electrons to be emitted instead.